# .Net 6 Blazor Not Able to Get Detailed Error Message

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I have a .Net 6 Blazor server side app.
The app has an error

> Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'.

I have tried setting the CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors = true.

I have ensured I am in Debug mode, i.e. the Environment.IsDevelopment switch is set to true.

Program.cs

```
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(x => x.DetailedErrors = true);
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
}
```

and I have set 'DetailedErrors: true'in appSettings.Developmnet.json and appSettings.json.

```
"AppSettings": {
    "DetailedErrors": true,
```

However this has not affected the error message in anyway.

I am still am unable to get the detailed error message.

Any ideas on what else to try?

---

Comment: builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
{
    options.DetailedErrors = true;
    options.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 100;
    options.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
    options.JSInteropDefaultCallTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    options.MaxBufferedUnacknowledgedRenderBatches = 10;
})
.AddCircuitOptions(opt => {opt.DetailedErrors = true;});

Comment: This is how I have done for .Net6 Blazor Server side project.

Comment: I have used your example, no changes though. I want to check that the program.cs file is being uploaded when I publish. I notice this file is not in the publish directory. Do you know where I would look to find the switches/settings that are set in the program.cs file?

Comment: Ok, check if the publish folder does have  'appsettings.production.json' file and make sure that does have your settings enabled.

Comment: It was adding the appsettings.production.json file that got it to work. Thank you so much! Please be sure to submit an answer so I can give you the credit. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make that the `appsettings.production.json` file is populating with the same flags in the publishing folder path. This happens normally when appsettings.json is different from `appsettings.{Environment}.json` file.